# FULL-TEXT Search in SQLite

Tags: database, indexing, full-text-search, sqlite

Simple question: does SQLite support FULL-TEXT searches?

If not, is there any way I can implement that feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [it does](http://kuujinbo.info/sqlite/fts.aspx).